# Is there a way to remove change tracking mechanism for a single entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have something like this:

```
var dbTransactions = context.Transactions.Where(t => t.Date >= yesterday).Select(t => t).ToList();
```

Now, i would like to remove objects from `dbTransactions` list, but not from the actual database. Later on i am calling `context.SaveChanges()` and if i would do that, it would erase rows from my db. How can i disable changes tracking for `dbTransactions`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168073/entity-framework-code-first-no-detach-method-on-dbcontext

Comment: Removing objects from a `List<T>` won't mark them as deleted in your `DbContext`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can use [AsNoTracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and for Transactions use Detach

```
Youcontext.YourEntities.AsNoTracking().Where);
```

or use

```
Youcontext.Transactions.Detach(obj);
```

Comment: Is there anything like a `[NoTracking]` attribute to use for POCO entities? How should we mark POCO entities (in our case lookup entities) as no-tracking?!

Answer (score 0):

Remove those entities from the context using [`Detach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach.aspx):

```
context.Transactions.Detach(obj);
```

so clearly you will have to recover that list - but then just iterate through it and detach them.