# Detach is not found in ef

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am following a video on MVVM.

There I have written a simple method by following the steps in video as follows :

```
[OperationContract]
public IEnumerable<Patient> GetPatients()
{
    using (Lab_Lite_Entities db = new Lab_Lite_Entities())
    {
        var result = db.Patients.ToList();
        result.ForEach(p => db.Detach(p)); //I get an error here.
        return result;
    }
}
```

But I get an error as follows:

```
Lab_Lite_Data.Lab_Lite_Entities does not contain a definition for 'Detach' and no
extension method 'Detach' accepting a first argument of type
'Lab_Lite_Data.Lab_Lite_Entities' could be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have added a reference to `System.Data.Entity` and `EntityFramework`.

I am using `Entity Framework 6.0`.

Comment: take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168073/entity-framework-code-first-no-detach-method-on-dbcontext

Comment: @Selman22 Thank you. It works perfectly. Please post the above link as answer.

Comment: If the correct answer to the question is to link to another question here on Stack Overflow, it should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error shows DbContext doesn't contain Detach method but there is an alternative way

[Entity Framework Code First - No Detach() method on DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168073/entity-framework-code-first-no-detach-method-on-dbcontext)